# How to create unique ID for each subject?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is the data:

| Subject code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 401 | John |
| 422 | Mary |
| 463 | Peter |

And I would like to create unique id based on the last two digit of the subject code. For example:

| ID | Subject code | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S01 | 401 | John |
| S22 | 422 | Mary |
| S63 | 463 | Peter |

Which library should I use? Should I use case_when() in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract`and `str_c` from the `stringr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(ID = str_c("S", str_extract(Subject_code, "\\d{2}$")))
  Subject_code  ID
1          401 S01
2          422 S22
3          463 S63
```

The regex pattern `\\d{2}$` matches the two `d`igits that occur in string-final (`$`) position and extracts them.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Subject_code = c(401, 422, 463))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `sub` like below

```
> transform(df, ID = sub(".", "s", SubjectCode))[c(3, 1, 2)]
   ID SubjectCode  Name
1 s01         401  John
2 s22         422  Mary
3 s63         463 Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` + `paste0`:

```r
data$ID <- paste0("S", substr(data$`Subject code`, 2, 3))
```

e.g.:

```r
paste0("S", substr(431, 2, 3))
#[1] "S31"
```

or in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(ID = paste0("S", substr(`Subject code`, 2, 3))
```